# How to display subcategories directly under parent category?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have categories and subcategories in the same table.
Parent category is identified as 0
and subcategory is identified as parent_id
In laravel blade file i want to display all the sub categories under the associated parent categories.

I have tried but shows sub categories in the all the parent categories.

```
view()->composer('Frontend.partial.navigation',function(){
    view()->share('categories',Category::where('parent_id',0)->get());
    view()->share('subcategories',Category::where('parent_id','!=',0)->get()); });
```

```
@foreach($categories as $cat)
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3" >
        <div class="bg5" >
          <h6 href="{{route('details')}}"><h6>{{$cat->categoryname}}</h6></a>
              @foreach($subcategories as $subcat)
              <a href="#"><p>{{$subcat->categoryname}}</p></a>
              @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

In this way it Doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@foreach($categories as $cat)
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3" >
    <div class="bg5" >
      <h6 href="{{route('details')}}"><h6>{{$cat->categoryname}}</h6></a>
          @foreach($subcategories as $subcat)
            @if($subcat->parent_id == $cat->id)
          <a href="#"><p>{{$subcat->categoryname}}</p></a>
            @endif
          @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

(assuming that the primary key of the categories is id)
i checked if the parent id of the subcategory is equal to the parent